# Emmet Extension in Vs Code shows overlapping suggestions

Tags: visual-studio-code, emmet

I have tried to install and uninstall Emmet and VScode itself but i do not know why this abbreviation keeps the suggestions overlapping  each other.

[image]

Comment: try a smaller editor/GUI font size

Comment: Hello @rioV8, I have tried that but still facing the same issue.

Comment: what's the value of your `editor.lineHeight` setting?

Comment: @starball, it is 45.

Comment: what if you increase it? and what about your `editor.suggestLineHeight` setting?